# Android: connecting two device without internet

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi, android-networking, adhoc

I am developing an application. In which the idea is like - i want to connect two devices as two mobile or two tabs or mobile to tab or mobile to server or tab to server. Means i want to send data from one device to other device mostly xml.

I want to connect two devices with out internet and blue tooth, I want to connect them with wifi having no internet. And than want to transfer data.

My point is i am having an application which is used to generate a xml and after generation of xml i want to send it to other device or tab or desktop server on a button click.

I searched on Google and found Ad-hoc network, but it is quite difficult to understand me. Is any other way by which i can easily understand Ad-hoc or other way by which i can connect.

So please guide me what should i do, how can I achieve my task. I need your guidance and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Socket connection would be a great idea in your situation, you dont need to have Internet to do so. Here is one of many examples if you google it: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use iJetty. iJetty can be configured to use in your application and when you start wifi router on one android device another can get connected on that device and if it's your client applciation you can configure it to look on a specific port.

Try this : http://puregeekjoy.blogspot.in/2011/06/running-embedded-jetty-in-android-app.html

Comment: Thank you Sumit for you suggestion. But my point is i am having an application which is used to generate a xml and after generation of xml i want to send it to other device or tab or desktop server. So suggest me that iJetty is useful for that also or should i do something else.

Comment: You can send that to other device or tab using iJetty :-
 - Start the hotspot on the device hosting the server.
 - Configure client application to detect server on a port now it will be able to detect server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Wi-Fi Direct](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) if your version of Android is 4.0 or later and your hardware works with it.